# Generate java class hierarchy from xml (plist)

Tags: java, xml, plist

Are there any tools that can automatically generate java class hierarchy from xml (plist)?

Say we have:

```
<blah>
    <item />
    <item />
</blah>
```

And we need to get something like:

```
class Blah {

Collection<Item> items;

}
```

...and so on and so forth

Comment: Why not use `JAXB` and annotation elements appropriately?

Comment: You may want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/686453/3340

Comment: Of course you need to generate a schema from the XML first, with a tool like trang or (better) manually.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, then the elements shall be transformed into class and field names.

This can be done with a few lines of code:

1. parse the xml document into a DOM
2. walk through the DOM tree and create a java source file in memory (StringBuilder)
3. write the source file to your file system

Or use XSLT to create a transformation from your xml document to a java source file.