# JAXB, XJC -> create multiple class files

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I'm using JAXB and XJC for first time.

I would like to generate Java classes from XML file so I use [this online helper](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx) to generate schema from XML file.

After that I just use this command line to generate Java classes :

```
xjc myschema.xsd
```

it's work but I receive only one Java file and many static classes inside it. Is this possible to generate many java files that contain only one classe per file please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 54, accepted):

By default [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) will create static inner classes for nested complex types to prevent class name conflicts.  You can use an external binding file to disable this behaviour.

**binding.xml**

A binding file allows you to customize how Java classes are generated from an XML schema.

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

The `-b` option is used with the XJC command to specify a binding file.

```
xjc -b binding.xml myschema.xsd
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/07/jaxb-xjc-and-nested-classes.html