# Jaxb, xjc: generate ONE single Java file out of Xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm usign xjc to generate java classes from my xsd. Obviously he is creating a single java file for each complexType.

Is it possible to configure xjc to use inner classes instead of creating every time a new file? The result should be that no madder how complex the xsd is, there should be only one outcomming file.

Version: xjc 2.2.8-b130911.1802

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such functionality.

You can [move inner classes to the top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175224/jaxb-xjc-create-multiple-class-files), but not the other way round.