# WSIMPORT- Unable to Generate non static inner classes in Client stubs

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I exposed a Web service written with Java. My Schema has Complex Types objects.

Everything is fine. When generate Client stubs with WSIMPORT command I noticed

here are static inner classes in the generated client stubs . To avoid

generating inner classes tried with

[JAXB, XJC -> create multiple class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175224/jaxb-xjc-create-multiple-class-files)

But getting an error A class/interface with the same name

"com.webservices.EducationDetails" is  already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this

conflict. But I could not find a way to resolve names in WSIMPORT.

## Questions

1. Generating Static Inner classes in WSIMPORT for ComplexType in XSD is default behavior?
2. Is there a way to avoid generating static inner classes in Web service Client Stubs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generating Static Inner classes in WSIMPORT for ComplexType in XSD is default behavior ?
   No. Web service client stub generation happens based on the configuration define in WSDL. (.xsd)
2. Is there a way to avoid generating static inner classes in Web service Client Stubs

It is hard to say without looking at your WSDL , Schema. I guess you have declared complex type in a way WSIMPORT generates inner classes for you. 
If you declare complex types as elements it should not generate inner classes.

Example

```
    <xs:element name="ResponseInformation" type="Response" /> 

<xs:complexType name="Response">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="testField1" />

        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

This is What I guess. Try to redefine the complex type. If you post your WSDL I can exactly tell where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks mate the issue was the way I declared my XSD

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, Iused the below command which generated me all the request response class properly. It has created inner static classes as well. You have to use -keep option

```
wsimport -keep C:\D_DRIVE\My_Work\USEI\SOAPService\OI_Manhattan_To_Consignor_EvreuxService_PreProd_Org.wsdl
```