# XJC -> create a unique class file

Tags: java, xjc

I'm using xjc for the first time. I would like to generate a unique java class from a xsd file, as follows:

```
xjc myfile.xsd
```

It works but I get several java files. Is it possible to generate a unique file containing static classes?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you want only one file?

Comment: It's a requirement for a project. Actually, I found an opposite case: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175224/jaxb-xjc-create-multiple-class-files)