# marshall with xjc created nested classes

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

```
<ProductInformation Context="GL">
 <Assets>
  <Asset ID="assetID" UserTypeID="ID">
    <Name>name</Name>
    <Reference ClassificationID="id"/>
      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="ID">Value1</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="ID">Value2</Value>
          <MultiValue AttributeID="attributeID">
             <Value>value3a</Value>
             <Value>value3b</Value>
          </MultiValue>
     </Values>
   </Asset>
 </Assets>

 <Products>....</Products>

</ProductInformation>
```

I used this xml->xsd and xjc to create classes from it.

Now I want to create my ProductInformation object,and marshall it.

My problem is xjc create 3 classes and a objectfactory, and some nested classes inside ProductInformation. When I look at the avaliable methods I mostly see getters instead of setters.

"Asset" class has no such methods like;

```
asset.setValues(List<Value> values)
```

Also I ended up writing funny code like this;

```
ProductInformation.Assets.Asset.Values.MultiValue multivalue=new ProductInformation.Assets.Asset.Values.MultiValue();
```

Is this normal with Jaxb?

Comment: Can you post specific parts of the generated code which causes issues? Usually everything should work fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way JAXB normally handles multi valued properties is to provide just a getter and no setter for the `List<Whatever>`, which returns a mutable list - you're supposed to call the getter to retrieve an initially-empty list and then create the member objects for this list using `new` in the normal way and `add` them directly to the list. You can `new` a static nested class in exactly the same way as a top-level one.

Single-valued properties (not lists) should have been generated with both getter and setter.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it, I updated the question could you check

Comment: so it s not weird that my Asset class is inner static inside ProductInfo?

Comment: @Spring yes, that screen shot looks correct, it's what I would expect JAXB to generate by default.

Comment: @Spring it uses static nested classes to avoid name clashes if two different types both have different nested elements with the same name.

Comment: @Spring - If you would like everything as a top level class see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/07/jaxb-xjc-and-nested-classes.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan tnx, you can also commit this as an answer as it is helpful

Comment: @Spring - As suggested I have added that information as an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13415487/383861

Answer (score 6):

The [**answer given by Ian Roberts**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414508/383861) is the correct one.  I am giving this one to provide some additional information for those people interested in not having inner classes.

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

If JAXB classes are generated from the following XML schema, both the resulting `Customer` and `Employee` classes will contain a static nested class called `Address` (because each contains their own definition of an address).  This is in fact why static nested classes are used to avoid name conflict problems.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/company"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/company"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xsd:element name="customer">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="address">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="employee">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="address">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="road" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

**JAXB Binding File (binding.xml)**

A bindings file is used to customize the schema to Java generation.  You can specify that everything should be a top level class with `localScoping="top-level"`.  When you do this you must make sure to resolve any potential name conflicts.

```xml
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="company.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='employee']/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='address']/xsd:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="EmployeeAddress"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

Below is an example of specifying a bindings file when using the XJC command to generate Java classes from an XML schema.

```
xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/07/jaxb-xjc-and-nested-classes.html

Answer (score 1):

This is actually just a comment to Blaise Doughan's answer but I want to post the xml.

If you work with a more complex xsd and the path in the `node` attribute is getting too long, you can:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="company.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='employee']">
            ....
                <jaxb:bindings node=".//xsd:element[@name='address']/xsd:complexType">
                    <jaxb:class name="EmployeeAddress"/>
                </jaxb:bindings>
            ....
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```