# parsing xml with records type

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I had got an xml data to parse into java Object. But this xml data with records is seeing first time,any body had an idea to parse this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Coder version="1.0">
  <record javaclass="com.dd.Impl">
    <value name="fileName">load</value>
    <record name="load" javaclass="com.wm.dd.Data">
      <value name="@version">1.0</value>
      <record name="lm:Order" javaclass="com.dd.Data">
        <value name="@Id"></value>
        <value name="@UID"></value>
        <value name="@Count">2</value>
        <value name="@Count">0</value>
        <record name="lm:Master" javaclass="com.dd.Data">
          <value name="lm:ID">13</value>
          <value name="lm:Number">382</value>
         </record>
        <array name="wo:Detail" type="record" depth="1">
          <record javaclass="com.dd.Data">
            <value name="lm:ID">13</value>
            <value name="lm:Number">382</value>
            <value name="lm:Code">CD3</value>
            <value name="lm:Occurrence">1</value>               
          </record>
          <record javaclass="com.dd.Data">
            <value name="lm:ID">13</value>
            <value name="lm:Number">382</value>
            <value name="lm:Code">CD2</value>
            <value name="lm:Occurrence">1</value>
          </record>
          <record javaclass="com.dd.Data">
           <value name="lm:ID">13</value>
            <value name="lm:Number">382</value>
            <value name="lm:Code">CD1</value>
            <value name="lm:Occurrence">1</value>
          </record>
         <record javaclass="com.dd.Data">
           <value name="lm:ID">13</value>
            <value name="lm:Number">382</value>
            <value name="lm:Code">CD4</value>
            <value name="lm:Occurrence">1</value>
          </record>              
        </array>
 </record>
    </record>
    <value name="folderPath">dir</value>
    <value name="value">2014</value>
  </record>
</ICoder>
```

Normally for parsing from xml to javaObjects usually use the jaxB code.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            try {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrderType .class);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                OrderType order = (OrderType ) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(order );
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should generate an XSD from your XML [see here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)
2. If you use maven you can generate from an XSD your java classes

   ```
          <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>0.9.0</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>commun-generate</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>generate</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                           <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                           <strict>true</strict>
                           <extension>true</extension>
                           <verbose>true</verbose>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
   ```

else see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686453/3364187) topic to generate class from xsd