# Generate list of all classes and methods in Java codebase

Tags: java

Is there any way to generate a list of all classes and methods in my Java codebase?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Can you give some example?

Comment: You mean classes, not objects, right?

Comment: Have you considered using reflection E.G. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html, maybe combined with some resource scanning to pick up all the classes?

Comment: want you get all objects from memory? ..... methods using reflection @RobertBain Bain solution

Comment: Wouldn't JavaDoc do this for you or are you looking to implement something similar? A recursive directory listing and finding method signatures in each found class perhaps?

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686453/generate-java-classes-from-xsd-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to get all *classes* and methods in the "codebase" (interpreting as `package`). This is not possible, as class loaders only serve requests for classes by returning the requested class, or by throwing an exception. Class loaders make no commitment to tell the VM what classes it may provide.

**EDIT**

A lot  can be achieved with the [reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections):

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.example.project", new SubTypesScanner(false));

 Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = 
     reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```