# Generate Java Classes From API XSDs

Tags: java, data-binding, xsd, amadeus

I'm currently working on the a Flight API integration on my company platform and I'm facing some issues.
I need to use a data binding plugin in order to generate Java classes based on the provided XSD files. 
Nevertheless, I have tried many plugins such as ADB, CXF or JIBX and I got binding errors with all of them.
I have been able to fix these errors by modifying the XSDs in order to "eliminate" the errors but I think I'll get issues later due to these changes.

So my question is quite simple, has anybody of you been able to find a good plugin which is able to handle the XSDs ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to generate java classes from XML schema ,please check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686453/generate-java-classes-from-xsd-files) .
If you want specific plugin for your IDE please check this for [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-java-code-from-xml-schema.html) and [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts008.htm).