# Read Nested tags of XSD in java

Tags: java, xsd

I have a requirement to read nested XSD tags in java. I am new to xsd.

Below is the sample xsd.  When I retrieve `EgwEquivUplmnList_Type`, I should get `EgwEquivUplmnList_Type` elements and `EgwUplmnArray_Type` elements [as it is nested tag of `EgwEquivUplmnList_Type` ] and `EgwUplmn_Type` elements [as it is nested tag of `EgwUplmnArray_Type`].

Is there an existing Java Parser to achieve this? or do I need to write a logic from scratch? Please guide me here.

I have used below code to read the xsd. But finding way to map nested elements...

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(getFile("sampleFiles\\icpm_schema_20151030_v1.xsd"));
```

//Sample Xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="EgwUplmn_Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="mcc" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
        <xs:element name="mnc" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="EgwUplmnArray_Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="uplmn">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ci" maxOccurs="16" type="EgwUplmn_Type"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="EgwEquivUplmnList_Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="length" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element name="plmn" type="EgwUplmnArray_Type"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686453/generate-java-classes-from-xsd-files?rq=1

Comment: Hi Mil4n,  I have checked the post.. But did not get much hints from it...

Comment: Is it possible to read the above example using JAXB. Please guide me here... If yes, Please point to some JAXB examples

Comment: What hints you missed in the linked question? you have several solutions listed there... JXB example you can find by simple search: for instance - http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
It is very tempting to immediately ask for hand-holding while developing. _But if you try at least to follow that example, write the code and execute it, you will learn so much more!_ Once you done with the example look at your problem and try to solve it... then if you questions ask.

Comment: I was able to achieve my goal by http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/ this site walk through....

Comment: So was anything of help to you in my comments?