# process xml with optional inner tags and values using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've got an `xml` file that looks like this

```
<console-menu-entry index="2" text="Print Hello World">
    <console-menu-entry index="1" text="Print Hello">
        print 'Hello'
    </console-menu-entry>
    <console-menu-entry index="2" text="Print World">
        print 'World'
    </console-menu-entry>
</console-menu-entry>
```

Basically node `<console-menu-entry>` may have either tags inside it or some text value.

How to process it using `jaxb`? When I do like this it fails with

```
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.
```

error.

My class looks like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name="console-menu-entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@ToString
public @Data class XmlConsoleMenuEntry {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String index;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String text;
    @XmlValue
    private String value;
    @XmlElement(name="console-menu-entry")
    private List<XmlConsoleMenuEntry> entries;
}
```

P.S. Using `jaxb` is not a requirement so if there is an approach using another library I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use JAXB but come from another end. Try to make use of xsd schema. This approach has a number of advantages:

1. Developing an XSD lets you understand your datamodel more deeply, detect possible flaws and see the data structure more clear.
2. You can [use XSD to generate the parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686453/generate-java-classes-from-xsd-files) which will help you to parse your xml (meeting that model) in a few lines of code
3. You can use XSD to create xml files (all the modern IDEs integrate XSD data in code-assistance mechanisms) so that you will get advice from IDE on which element would fit your datamodel in a particular place, which attribute is requited for a particular element (even which values are suitable for that attrubute) and many other usefule things

Below is the example of xsd schema which will let you generate parser which parses your example (you should only provide appropriate namespace for your xml elements)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://some.your.schema"
           xmlns:tns="http://some.your.schema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="ConsoleMenuEntry" mixed="true" >
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tns:console-menu-entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="index" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="console-menu-entry" type="tns:ConsoleMenuEntry"/>

</xs:schema>
```

You now can generate the parser files (Windows example)

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\xjc" -d ../src -p your.app.generated test.xsd
```

Where `-d ../src` specifies the path on hard drive where your parser classes would be located, `-p your.app.generated` specifies the package for you generated parser classes and `test.xsd` is the schema file name

Here is the example of `test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<console-menu-entry xmlns="http://some.your.schema" index="1" text="Some new text">
    <console-menu-entry index="1" text="some other text">
        sdfsdkljf
    </console-menu-entry>
    <console-menu-entry index="2" text="some other text"/>
</console-menu-entry>
```

And the code that parses it:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        ConsoleMenuEntry rootEntry = ((JAXBElement<ConsoleMenuEntry>) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File("PATH_TO_FILE\\test.xml"))).getValue();
        processMenuEntry(rootEntry);
    }

    private static void processMenuEntry(ConsoleMenuEntry menuEntry) {
        System.out.println("Index (attr) = " + menuEntry.getIndex() + ", Text (attr) = '" + menuEntry.getText() + "'");

        for (Serializable element : menuEntry.getContent()) {
            if (element instanceof JAXBElement) {
                processMenuEntry(((JAXBElement<ConsoleMenuEntry>) element).getValue());
            } else if (element instanceof String) {
                String innerText = element.toString().trim();
                if (innerText.length() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Inner text: '" + innerText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh indeed. Did not think about schema and generation of parser. Thanks!